# How to update multiple tables at the same time?

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to update fields from three different tables but I'm getting some errors:

```
UPDATE 
  a, b, c
SET 
  a.Locked = 0, 
  b.Locked = 0, 
  c.Locked = 0, 
  a.LockedByUsername = 'zolomon', 
  b.LockedByUsername = 'zolomon', 
  c.LockedByUsername = 'zolomon', 
  a.LockedAt = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  b.LockedAt = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  c.LockedAt = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM 
  TableA AS a
  INNER JOIN TableB as b ON n.Objid = o.Objid
  INNER JOIN TableC as c ON n.Namnid = e.Namnid 
WHERE
  a.Namn1 = 'FirstName LastName' AND b.objektkod='SomeIdentifier'
```

And the errors:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can't update fields from multiple tables on a single `update` query. There error you are getting is because this is not permitted:

```
update a, b, c
```

Since you can only update **one table** per `update` command.

Comment: So I should create a transaction and perform the same update for the three different tables (they all contain the specified fields/columns) instead?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, or as `dnl` suggested in other answer, you can encapsulate your updates on a stored procedure.

Comment: @FarlingOpptreden: didn't know you could do that in SQLServer. It's a pretty neat idea.

Comment: @Pablo - You can't. You would get the error "View or function 'v' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables."

Comment: @Martin: I see. Yeah. Suspected that. But since @FarligOpptreden was so sure about it and even posted a code snippet, it made me doubt. :-)

Comment: I deleted my snippet. Tried it out and it didn't work. :( Seeing as I've only done it a couple of times before and, incidentally, only updating columns from a single table even though multiple were joined, it worked... In this instance it won't, though.

Comment: Is this documented? I've read the `UPDATE` documentation but I couldn't see it.

Answer (score 8):

As pointed out by other answers, in SQL an `UPDATE` updates only one table. That's normally enough for most practical needs. If you want to update several tables *at the same time*, you can just put the updates inside a transaction, and the effect will normally be the same.

If you are concerned about getting different timestamps (for your field `lockedAt`) first look into your database docs to check if your `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` function refers to the start time of the transaction (e.g. [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)).

Answer (score 6):

you cannot update multiple tables in one statement. an option would be to use a stored procedure

Comment: +1 like the idea of a stored procedure. I always forget that MSSQLServer users looooooove store procedures.

Answer (score -6):

We can update it with join like this

```
UPDATE table1 
INNER join table2 on table1.id=table2.tab1_id
INNER join table3 on table1.id=table3.tab1_id
SET table1.status=1,table2.status=1,table3.status=1,table1.name='Premjith'
WHERE table1.id=1
```

Comment: this is not valid in T-sql

Comment: You can't update fields from multiple tables on a single update query.

Comment: This answer is correct for MySQL, but the OP asked about tsql.