# How to Combine SQL update statements into single statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I have the following SQL Server tables. For the purpose of my question, the there can only be one "Person" with a given name (`Person`, or a combination of `Person` + `Year` is the primary key to the tables).

```
DailySalesSummary
+------+--------+---------+------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| Year | Person | Family  | City | PersonSales | FamilySales | CitySales |
+------+--------+---------+------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| 2013 | Jim    | Smith   |    1 | $10         | $10         | $10       |
| 2013 | Anna   | Smith   |    1 | $0          | $10         | $10       |
| 2013 | John   | Stewart |    3 | $8          | $8          | $13       |
| 2013 | Todd   | Johnson |    3 | $4          | $5          | $13       |
| 2013 | Alan   | Johnson |    3 | $1          | $5          | $13       |
+------+--------+---------+------+-------------+-------------+-----------+

SalesSummary
+------+--------+-------------+-----------+
| Year | Person | FamilySales | CitySales |
+------+--------+-------------+-----------+
| 2013 | Jim    | $55         | $55       |
| 2013 | Anna   | $55         | $55       |
| 2013 | John   | $24         | $39       |
| 2013 | Todd   | $10         | $39       |
| 2013 | Alan   | $5          | $39       |
+------+--------+-------------+-----------+

Reference
+--------+--------+------+
| Person | Family | City |
+--------+--------+------+
| Jim    | Smith  | 1    |
| …      | …      | …    |
+--------+--------+------+
```

I want to update the `SalesSummary` table with the contents of the `DailySalesSummary` table. I have done it the following way:

```
UPDATE SalesSummary 
  SET FamilySales = SalesSummary.FamilySales + p.FamilySales 
FROM DailySalesSummary p,
     Reference bx
WHERE SalesSummary.Person= bx.Person
  AND bx.City = p.City
  AND bx.Family = p.Family
  AND SalesSummary.Year = p.Year

UPDATE SalesSummary
  SET CityTotal = SalesSummary.FamilyTotal + p.FamilyTotal
FROM DailySalesSummary p,
     Reference bx
WHERE SalesSummary.Person = bx.Person
  AND bx.City = p.City
  AND SalesSummary.Year = p.Year
```

I would like to find a way to combine the two update statements into a single update statement that will take care of everything, but I can't figure out the exact structure needed.

Apologize if the necessary solution is offensively easy, but I appreciate any help.

Comment: You could try first combining the datagrabs from your `DailySalesSummary` and `Reference` tables into two `SELECT` statements combined with an appropriate `UNION ALL` for common columns, insert those values into a temp table or table variable (perhaps with an additional flag column to distinguish the separate data sets), then perform a single `UPDATE` using the temp table to join.

Comment: What do the results look like *after* the update?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a single update:

```
UPDATE SalesSummary
  SET FamilySales = SalesSummary.FamilySales + (case when bx.Family = p.Family then p.FamilySale else 0 end),
      CityTotal = SalesSummary.FamilyTotal + p.FamilyTotal
FROM DailySalesSummary p,
     Reference bx
WHERE SalesSummary.Person = bx.Person
  AND bx.City = p.City
  AND SalesSummary.Year = p.Year;
```

This will set `FamilySales` to itself in rows that do not match the `bx.Family = p.Family` condition.  But it should have the same effect as your two queries.

EDIT:

The following seems to work on the data you have:

```
UPDATE ss 
    set FamilySales = ss.FamilySales + dss.FamilySales,
        CitySales = ss.CitySales + dss.CitySales
FROM SalesSummary ss join
     DailySalesSummary dss
     on ss.Person = dss.Person and
        ss.City = dss.City
        ss.Family = dss.Family;
```

I don't understand why there is a join to the `bx` table.  You can still do it if you want to filter things out.

As far as I can tell, the data in `DailySalesSummary` is aligned with what needs to be updated, so a simple `join` brings the right rows together.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I just tested it out and it appears to work. I figured some kind of CASE statement might be the answer, but I just couldn't make it work. You've been a great help.

Comment: On second pass, the query doesn't appear to be equivalent. It's not updating the family sales properly.

Comment: I appreciate your help! I noticed that, for example, I have 2 entries in DailySalesSummary: both in `City` "3", Both in `Family` "Stewart", and one entry is for `Person` "John", (which currently exists as a record in SalesSummary) and the other is for `Person` "Steve" (Which does not yet exist in SalesSummary and will be inserted in some capacity after the update.) The combined update statement will correctly update the `CityTotal` on the John record, but will hit the `ELSE` path of the `CASE` statement when attempting to set the new `FamilyTotal`. It's a mystery to me why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can't `UPDATE` more than one table with a single `UPDATE` statement. More information can be found at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154615/how-to-update-multiple-tables-at-the-same-time) Stack Overflow answer.

If the all the columns that are being updated are in the same table and come from the same source tables, then you can simply update multiple columns, doing something like this:

```
UPDATE SalesSummary 
  SET FamilySales = SalesSummary.FamilySales + p.FamilySales,
      CityTotal = SalesSummary.FamilyTotal + p.FamilyTotal
FROM DailySalesSummary p,
     Reference bx
WHERE SalesSummary.Person= bx.Person
  AND bx.City = p.City
  AND bx.Family = p.Family
  AND SalesSummary.Year = p.Year
```

Although I wouldn't recommend `SQL 2000`-style joins. Reworking it would look like this:

```
UPDATE SalesSummary
SET FamilySales = SalesSummary.FamilySales + p.FamilySales,
    CityTotal = SalesSummary.FamilyTotal + p.FamilyTotal
FROM
    DailySalesSummary p
    JOIN Reference bx ON bx.City = p.City
     AND bx.Family = p.Family
WHERE
    SalesSummary.Year = p.Year
    AND SalesSummary.Person = bx.Person
```

### Updated Answer

```
UPDATE s
SET
    s.FamilySales = s.FamilySales + fam.FamilySales,
    s.CitySales = s.CitySales + city.CitySales
FROM
    SalesSummary s
    JOIN Reference r ON r.Person = s.Person
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Year, Family, FamilySales FROM DailySalesSummary) fam ON fam.Family = r.Family AND fam.Year = s.Year
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Year, City, CitySales FROM DailySalesSummary) city ON city.City = r.City AND city.Year = s.Year
```

You can see [a working example here at SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5a3fb/1).

Comment: I know my question was convoluted--my apologies--but I don't believe you understood exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. I appreciate the tip on joins, but I've been told to use the old method for consistency.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand what you're requesting. The problem is you've got two 'categories' or 'sets' of data within a single table and want to aggregate both and update them all at once. In other words, you've got both City and its sales as well as person, family, and their sales, all within one denormalized table.

Comment: Either way, I think I devised a way to do it. Take a look at my updated answer. I did it with `JOIN`s, feel free to re-engineer it with the method you've been told to use.