# Updating multiple tables JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

is updating multiple tables possible the way I'm trying to do it?
And if so can anybody see what's wrong with my code, I'm getting a command not properly ended syntax error

```
public void updateProdCD(DigiProduct p)
{

        try {

            String queryString = "UPDATE Product SET p.prod_id=?,"                    
                                 +" p.prod_type=?, "
                                 +" c.album_name=?,  "
                                 +" c.cd_cost_price=?, " 
                                 +" c.cd_sale_price=?, "
                                 +" p.current_stock=?,  "
                                 +" dp.age_rating=?, " 
                                 +" dp.genre=?,  "
                                 +" c.record_company=?,  "
                                 +" c.album_length=? "
            +" FROM product p, digital_product dp, "
            +" cd c, artist a, cd_artist ca "
                    +"WHERE dp.prod_id = p.prod_id "
                    +"AND dp.dig_id = c.dig_id "
                    +"AND a.artist_id = ca.artist_id "
                    +"AND c.cd_id = ca.cd_id "
                    +"AND prod_id ="+ "'" + p.getProd_id() + "'";

            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);
            pstmt.setString(1, p.getProd_id() );
            pstmt.setString(2, p.getProd_type());
            pstmt.setString(3, p.getAlbumName());
            pstmt.setDouble(4, p.getCostPrice());
            pstmt.setDouble(5, p.getSellPrice());
            pstmt.setInt(6, p.getCurrent_stock());
            pstmt.setString(7, p.getAge_rating() );
            pstmt.setString(8, p.getGenre());
            pstmt.setString(9, p.getPublisher());
            pstmt.setDouble(10, p.getLength());
            pstmt.executeUpdate();


            updateAlbum(p);

            }catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why didn't you parametrize the last prod_id?

Comment: I'm going to change it when I have the rest working, it was giving me a different error when I did it like the others.

Comment: Is this SQL will execute properly ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update multiple tables at the same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154615/how-to-update-multiple-tables-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Looks like I have to rewrite it to do one table at a time so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UPDATE some_table SET [fields_list] FROM [tables] WHERE [predicates]` is incorrect SQL syntax. It is impossible to update fields of several tables in one query, unless it's a stored procedure call.

Try

`UPDATE table_name SET [fields_list] WHERE [predicates]`.

Try to look at this question: [How to update multiple tables at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154615/how-to-update-multiple-tables-at-the-same-time)

Comment: This did not work, if I remove the FROM how will the query know what tables I want to update?

Comment: You have to update fields of **one** table per one `UPDATE` query.

Comment: The basic syntax is valid with SQL Server, however you can only update the `some_table`, not those from `[tables]`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel eh.. can you please give me a clue what does it mean `update table set [fields] from ...`? I understand that `select` clause may be used to get data neccesary to build predicates after `where`, but that kind of syntax really makes me confused. If you can post a link about this topic, I will appreciate that aswell.

Comment: I have had to rewrite my code, based on what I've read what I was trying to do was not possible, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Johntk You are welcome. Do not forget to upvote useful posts and mark best as correct.

Comment: @AlexeyMalev See the [SQL Server documentation for `UPDATE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) the `FROM` is essentially used to query data for the update statement (with some additional quirks if you include the table to update in the from as well).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for the information, appreciated it.