# update in sql server with joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my code in sql server

I have an error saying"The multi-part identifier "t2.isactive" could not be bound."

also, I want to do this update in one command and one command only

thanks for help

```
UPDATE tb_active_priority_alert  
SET 
priority_alert_guid = t2.priority_alert_guid,
priority_alert_title = t2.priority_alert_title,
priority_alert_zone = t2.priority_alert_zone,
priority_alert_color =t2.priority_alert_color,
priority_alert_allow_cancel = t2.priority_alert_allow_cancel,
priority_alert_time_duration = t2.priority_alert_time_duration,
priority_alert_type = t2.priority_alert_type,
priority_alert_text = t2.priority_alert_text,
web_url =t2.web_url,
video_url = t2.video_url,
video_style = t2.video_style,
banner_playlist_guid = t2.banner_playlist_guid,
signage = t2.signage,
signage_guid = t2.signage_guid,
alert_icon = t2.alert_icon,
isactive ='true',
user_guid =t2.user_guid,
creation_datetime =   GETDATE(),
expiration_datetime = dateadd(MINUTE,t2.priority_alert_time_duration,GETDATE()),
t2.isactive='true'
from  tb_users_priority_alerts  t2 left outer join tb_active_priority_alert t1 on t2.priority_alert_guid =@priority_alert_guid
WHERE t2.priority_alert_guid =@priority_alert_guid;
```

Comment: Use proper JOIN condition `on t2.priority_alert_guid =t1.thejoiningcolumn`

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on with out seeing your table definitions. Can you post your table definitions for t1 and t2? The multi-part identifier could not be bound error is basically saying that SQL can't find the column isactive in tb_active_priority_alert t1. This is oversimplified, but that's the basic idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't make it work.
the statement:

```
t2.isactive='true'
```

is trying to update a table that is not the one stated in the first row of your statement.
update instruction can update data in a single table/object; what you are trying to do is update data in 2 different tables at once and this is not supported.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154615/how-to-update-multiple-tables-at-the-same-time) you can find the very same question answered on SO.
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177523.aspx) you can find official MS documentation about `UPDATE`; it is not explicitly written but in each and every reference to the item to be updated you will find a single object as target and even in the syntax guide there is only one target expected.


you can go with 2 separate update statements in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your join with t1. You have to join the two tables on a specific id/value/whatever.

try this instead:

```
from  tb_users_priority_alerts  t2 
left join tb_active_priority_alert t1 on t2.priority_alert_guid = t1.priority_alert_guid
```

instead of t2.priority_alert_guid =@priority_alert_guid

Comment: I can't do this because 
t1 will permanently has one column only 
which is not be in t2
so I want to update t1 without any conditions

Comment: So why will you join t1 onto the select-statement?

Answer (score 0):

In your query you shown isactive='true' it throws error even i think isactive 
column in both tables and here u don't mention tb_active_priority_alert.isactive so it gives error.

And u again mention below t2.isactive='true' so there is no need of isactive='true' two times here .