# Multiple table UPDATE using SELECT that requires JOIN using PGAdmin

Tags: postgresql

I am using PGAdmin III and postgres 9.6

I have postgres schemas that consists of 250 tables with various columns. Two tables are of similar names and have the same columns, but unique data and IDs. I want to UPDATE one column in both tables with a specific number but choosing which rows get updated is complicated.

I have a script which correctly works on one table at a time, but I wonder if it can be done in a single script. I have tried using DO and LOOP but keep running into roadblocks.

Here's the working single-table script:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET number = 44
WHERE table1.id IN
  (SELECT table1.id FROM plan
   JOIN name ON name.id = plan.nameid
   JOIN type ON type.id = name.typeid
   JOIN simul ON simul.id = plan.simulid
   LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.id = tableid
   WHERE type.tag = 'X' AND plan.class LIKE '%Table%' AND simul.label IN 
  ('SIMUL90','SIMUL99','SIMUL87'));
```

"plan.class" contains text which determines class of simul and thus either Table1 or Table2. Table1 and Table2 are of identical column structure but their IDs may be identical so UNION is out of consideration. TH other joins are to fine tune the SELECT so I get only a small subset of the table. The number to update is the same for either table.

Comment: Here's a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5154615/5298879). Long story short, you can't update multiple tables in one plain SQL query, but you can within one transaction or PL/pgSQL block.

Comment: You can combine several data-modifying statements together using a Common Table Expressions (CTE), see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

Comment: Thanks for responding.