# Is it possible to execute a SQL update statement for a list of tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to remove the value for a specific column in multiple SQL Server tables using an `UPDATE` statement.

Using T-SQL, is it possible to store the tables in a list, then use a for each loop to execute the same SQL update statement to every single table in the list?

This is easy to do in a programming language like Python where you just specify

```
for table in tables:
    Update statement
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update multiple tables at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154615/how-to-update-multiple-tables-at-the-same-time)

Comment: do you want to make it dynamic ? i mean the list of tables. And, the update statement is always the same ?

Comment: Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069024/syntax-of-for-loop-in-sql-server, loop over the tables and use sp_executesql.

Comment: @Luuk no I'm not trying to update multiple table at the same time. I'm trying to repeat the same update SQL statement for a specified list of tables.

Comment: @ewramner I don't think it can iterate through a list of tables. It looks like I can only use the WHILE clause to iterate through a fixed number.

Comment: You can use a while clause with an index that selects a given table and stop when the index reaches the end of the list, but I see that you have an answer already.

Comment: @J100: "It looks like I can only use the WHILE clause to iterate through a fixed number", please re-read [WHILE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), paragraph A with the example: "(SELECT AVG(ListPrice) FROM Production.Product) < $300". This average is definitely not a fixed number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use dynamic SQL to build and execute a single SQL statement, no looping required, you could build on something like:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
with t as (
    select n from(values('Table1'),('Table2'),('Table3'))t(n) /* My list of tables*/
)
select @sql = String_Agg(Concat('Update ', QuoteName(n), ' set col = 5 where col = 4; '),'')
from t;

exec(@sql);
```

See [Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2c5b53c404f7fb55e8dd1ead0a858f8e&hide=1)

Answer (score 0):

You have bunch of options to make it really dynamic and flexible i created a potential solution that might meet your needs, the approach consist in [Sql Cursors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) , [temp tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16) and [dynamic execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d02de/24)

```
declare @updateStatement nvarchar(150)
declare @myList table (updateStatement nvarchar(150))
insert into @myList values
('update TableA set valA=''AUpdated'' where valA=''ANotUpdated'''),
('update TableB set valB=''BUpdated'''),
('update TableC set valC=''CUpdated''')

declare C cursor local fast_forward for
SELECT updateStatement
FROM @myList
  
OPEN C  
  
FETCH NEXT FROM C   
INTO @updateStatement
  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN    
  
      exec (@updateStatement)   

    FETCH NEXT FROM C   
    INTO @updateStatement

    END   

CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C
```